# How to separate date and time in php?

Tags: php, date, datetime, datetime-format

my date format is like : `Wednesday, 22 Apr, 2015, 12:39 PM`

How i separate date and time like Below ?

> >
>   Date :- April 22 2015
>
> >
>   Time :- 12:39 PM

Comment: use explode to separate the...result

Comment: This date string is auto generate or manual

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First remove the commas and use `strtotime`:

```
$dt = 'Wednesday, 22 Apr 2015, 12:39 PM';
$dt = strtotime(str_replace(',', '', $dt));
$d = date('F d Y',$dt);
$t = date('h:i A',$dt);
echo $d,'<br/>',$t;
```

Output:

```
April 22 2015
12:39 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Date and Time string and sperate it below,

```
$time = new DateTime("2015-04-22 18:00:01");
$date = $time->format('n.j.Y');
$time = $time->format('H:i');
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are giving that date as a string. try below code..
first spiting it by space and , will give you the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Wednesday
    [1] => 22
    [2] => Apr
    [3] => 2015
    [4] => 12:39
    [5] => PM
)
```

following is the code for splitting and extracting date and time seoarately

```
$dateTime = 'Wednesday, 22 Apr, 2015, 12:39 PM';
$dateArray = array_map('trim', preg_split( "/[\s,]+/", $dateTime ));
$date = $dateArray [2].' '.$dateArray [1].' '.$dateArray [3];
$time = $dateArray [4].' '.$dateArray [5];
echo $date;
echo $time;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use explode like below to separate the string into different pieces and than combine whatever pieces you like in your code

```
    <?php $date="Wednesday, 22 Apr, 2015, 12:39 PM";
$date=explode(',',$date);

echo "Date".':-'.$date[1].' '.$date[2]."<br/>";
echo "Time".':-'.$date[3];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
$dateTime = 'Wednesday, 22 Apr, 2015, 12:39 PM';
 $splitDate = explode(',', $dateTime);
 echo "date => ".$splitDate[1].' '.$splitDate[2];
 echo "time =>".array_pop($splitDate);
```